# RTL viewer diagram shows no logic gates

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, schematics

I'm trying to write a Verilog gate-level description of this circuit:

[image: diagram]

My code is here. I compile it on Quartus II (there is no error):

```
module practicechapter3 (F, A, B, C, D);
output  F;
input   A, B, C, D;
wire    B_bar, C_bar, w1, w2, w3, w4;
not     (B_bar, B);
not     (C_bar, C);
nand    G1 (w1, C, D);
and     G2 (w2, w1, B_bar);
nand    G3 (w3, w2, A);
nand    G4 (W4, B, C_bar);
nand    G5 (F, w3, w4);
endmodule
```

However, when I created the RTL viewer:

[image]

The result doesn't resemble what I imagined (like Fig 3.20b).
How can I make it resemble the Fig 3.20b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog is case-sensitive.  `W4` is different from `w4`.   Change:

```
nand    G4 (W4, B, C_bar);
```

to:

```
nand    G4 (w4, B, C_bar);
```

A good way to catch errors such as this is to add the following compiler directive to your Verilog source code:

```
`default_nettype none
```

You should get a compile error something like this:

```
Error-[IND] Identifier not declared
  Identifier 'W4' has not been declared yet. If this error is not expected, 
  please check if you have set `default_nettype to none.
```